# Python Fabric logging errors

Tags: python, fabric

I am trying to understand how fabric's logger module works. 
I run on the command line:

```
 $ fabfile -I task-1
```

I of course get output to the console showing me the execution of the task on each of the remote hosts connected to.
Bu how can I redirect the output of errors to a logfile on my local machine and put a timestamp on it?
Does fabric's logger module provide this? Or should I use Python's logging module. Either one, I am not sure how to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Fabric does not feature logging to a file (see [issue #57](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/57))

But there is a workaround using the `logging` module, which I find pretty nice.

First, configure your logger:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s',
    filename="out.log",
    filemode='a'
)
```

And then wrap the portions of your code which are likely to throw errors with a `try/catch` block like this:

```
try:
    #code
except:
    logging.exception('Error:')
```

The logger will print `'Error:'` and the exception's stacktrace to "out.log"